# Is it ok to have water when hungry?

Tags: hunger-hungry

The other night, I was getting ready to wind up work and leave for home. I was feeling terribly hungry. But there was no food available nearby and it would be at least an hour before I got home. So, to curb my hunger pangs I drank some water before my hunger subsided somewhat. It was enough to keep me going till I got home. Is it the right thing to drink water when you are feeling extremely hungry (assuming that there is no food available nearby) ?

If not, what should I have done to curb my hunger pangs?